# How to specify a list of generics of unknown/arbitrary size

Tags: flowtype, typechecking, static-typing

**Note**: I started a [discussion on Github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7488) about this subject.

I have a **zip** function, for now it is typed for iterables of the same type `T`. I would like to have this typed for arbitrary mixed input type but still conserving the matching output type, for example, if the input type `[Iterable<T>, Iterable<U>]` I want the output type to be `Iterable<[T, U]>`. Is it possible to have this for arbitrary input size? I basically want to say, *if you have this list of type as input you'll have them as output*.

Here is the current version of my **zip**:

```
export function *zip<T>(...iterables:Array<Iterable<T>>): Iterable<Array<T>> {
   const iterators = iterables.map(iterable => iter(iterable));
   while(true){
      const items = iterators.map(iterator => iterator.next());
      if (items.some(item => item.done)){
         return;
      }
      yield ((items.map(item => { return item.value }): Array<any>): Array<T>);
  }
}

export function *iter<T>(iterable:Iterable<T>): Iterator<T> {
   yield* iterable;
}
```

---

Current [best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701783/1720199) by [AndrewSouthpaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2672869/andrewsouthpaw):

```
declare function zip<A, B>(Iterable<A>, Iterable<B>): Iterable<[A, B]>;
declare function zip<A, B, C>(Iterable<A>, Iterable<B>, Iterable<C>): Iterable<[A, B, C]>;
declare function zip<A, B, C, D>(Iterable<A>, Iterable<B>, Iterable<C>, Iterable<D>): Iterable<[A, B, C, D]>;
export function *zip<T>(...iterables:Array<Iterable<T>>): Iterable<Array<T>> {
   const iterators = iterables.map(iterable => iter(iterable));
   while(true){
      const items = iterators.map(iterator => iterator.next());
      if (items.some(item => item.done)){
         return;
      }
      yield ((items.map(item => { return item.value }): Array<any>): Array<T>);
  }
}
```

It works as expected when called with 4, 3 or 2 iterables, when called with 5 or more arguments flow will simply say that zip can only be called with 4 or less arguments. Of course we could add as many function signature as we like to get it to work for 5, 6 or any number N of arguments, but that would require to declare N distinct signatures (which is a bit ugly). On the other hand this strategy does not allow to have an unbounded number of arguments (like the spread operator does). I'm still looking for that.

---

This raised a more general question, is there any language in which this exists?

I really have the feeling that this can be done in theory (not necessarily in flow), on the other hand I can't recall of a statically typed language in which I've done/seen that (I would also be interested in seeing this kind of type checking in any language).

To be a bit more specific, my feeling is that if you have a type checking system in which (by definition) all types are statically known (any variable has a known type `x`) then function `f: Array<Iterable<x>> -> Iterable<Array<x>>` is always called on a known type `x`. Therefore we should be able to statically decide what type `f` will return given `x` (whether `x` is a single generic type or a list of generic types).

The same goes for the function itself, if you  have a type `x` as input, then you only need to check that your function preserve type `x`.

Maybe this needs to be defined recursively in some languages, that would also be interesting to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution. All credit goes to [jbrown215](https://github.com/jbrown215) from Flow team, he found the idea of [using `$ReadOnlyArray<mixed>`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7488#issuecomment-467123778) here:

```js
export function *zip<T: $ReadOnlyArray<mixed>>(...iterables:Array<Iterable<T>>): Iterable<Array<T>> {
   const iterators = iterables.map(iterable => iter(iterable));
   while(true){
      const items = iterators.map(iterator => iterator.next());
      if (items.some(item => item.done)){
         return;
      }
      yield ((items.map(item => { return item.value }): Array<any>): Array<T>);
  }
}

export function *iter<T>(iterable:Iterable<T>): Iterator<T> {
   yield* iterable;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We've only been able to accomplish this through overriding the function signature declaration. This might help:

```
declare function zip<A, B>(Iterable<A>, Iterable<B>): Iterable<[A, B]>
declare function zip<A, B, C>(Iterable<A>, Iterable<B>, Iterable<C>): Iterable<[A, B, C]>
declare function zip<A, B, C, D>(Iterable<A>, Iterable<B>, Iterable<C>, Iterable<D>): Iterable<[A, B, C, D]>
export function zip(a, b, c, d) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's almost what I'm looking for. Do you think it is possible to have the same for not only 3 but any number (potentially big) of iterables? Ideally I would even like something that would work for unbounded input size, but I guess this would be hard to achieve (and maybe overkill).

Comment: I haven't found a way yet. You can always try opening an issue with flow but that's a mixed bag. In cases like yours, I just create a stupid number of overloads that accommodate a large number of iterables. If you're talking like 10+ or 100s or 1000s, then I'd just accept that we're trying to put types on a dynamic language and by its very nature we can't have everything.

Comment: I'm not sure to see why it would not be possible (not with flow, but in theory). I guess I'll try to open an issue on that, just for the sake of understanding why it's not possible if it is the case. I'll update my question as I go.